# Using connect and disconnect for different progress bars in an if in qt

Tags: c++, qt

I'm still learning how to use Qt (in fact it's my first day doing so) and I've hit a snag when it comes to signals. I wanted to have a slider whose value is copied by a progress bar until said progress bar's value hits 50. Once it does, another progress bar will "take over" and continue copying the value of the slider.

Here is my code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow){
    ui->setupUi(this);

    ui->progressBar->setValue(ui->horizontalSlider->value());
    ui->progressBar_2->setValue(ui->horizontalSlider->value());

    //connecting the slider with the second progress bar
    connect(ui->horizontalSlider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), ui->progressBar_2, SLOT(setValue(int)));


    if(ui->progressBar_2->value() == 50){ //once the progress bar 2 reach 50
        //disconnects the connection it had with the slider
        disconnect(ui->horizontalSlider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), ui->progressBar_2, SLOT(setValue(int))); 
        //The first progress bar takes on the slider's value (50)
        ui->progressBar->setValue(ui->horizontalSlider->value()); //could also have ui->progressBar->setValue(50) 
        //connect the slider with the first progress bar
        connect(ui->horizontalSlider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), ui->progressBar, SLOT(setValue(int))); 
    }

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow(){
        delete ui;
}
```

I do not know why the if condition is ignored. Is it the way I wrote the condition or am I not understanding something with the connect() and disconnect() functions?

Comment: You're only checking for 50 once, during construction, at which point it's clearly not the current value. That `if` obviously needs to be moved out into a signal handler that will evaluate it every time the value changes.

Answer (score 3):

The `if` condition will have no meaning outside the constructor where your horizontal slider value is changing. The easiest way here is to connect to a slot where you filter the value and change the slider values. For example, create a slot named `updateSliders(int)` and then connect it with:

```
connect(ui->horizontalSlider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),
        this, SLOT(updateSliders(int)));
```

Here's a suitable implementation of the slot:

```
void MainWindow::updateSliders(int value)
{
  if (value > 50) {
    ui->progressBar_2->setValue(value);
  } else {
    ui->progressBar->setValue(value);
  }
}
```